# eval function does not work correctly in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, eval

I am new in JavaScript & I am creating a simple calculator.

But I have some problems with the `eval()` function.

My script:

```
function calc(fld){
    var firstNo = 0 ;
    var secNo   = 0 ;
    var num = fld.name.charAt(2);
    var op  = fld.name.charAt(0);

    if(op == "t"){op = "-";}
    else if(op == "z"){op = "*";}
    else if(op == "e"){op = "=";}
    else if(op == "j"){op = "+";}
    else if(op == "d"){op = "/";}
    else { op ="";}

    if (op != "=") {eval("document.calc1.res").value  += num +  op ;}
    else { 
        // This line doesn't work correctly
        document.calc1.res.value = eval("document.calc1.res.value") ;
        // nor this one
        // document.calc1.res.value = eval("document.calc1.res").value ;    
    }
```

And this is the HTML:

```
<form id="calc" name="calc1" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="res" id="res"><br />
        <input type="button" value="7" id="no7"  name="no7" onclick="calc(this)"></input type="button" value=""><input type="button" value="8" id="no8" name="no8" onclick="calc(this)"></input type="button" value=""><input type="button" value="9" id="no9" name="no9" onclick="calc(this)"></input type="button" value=""><br />
        <input type="button" value="4" id="no4" name="no4" onclick="calc(this)"></input type="button" value=""><input type="button" value="5" id="no5" name="no5" onclick="calc(this)"></input type="button" value=""><input type="button" value="6" id="no6" name="no6" onclick="calc(this)"></input type="button" value=""><br />
        <input type="button" value="1" id="no1" name="no1" onclick="calc(this)"></input type="button" value=""><input type="button" value="2" id="no2" name="no2" onclick="calc(this)"></input type="button" value=""><input type="button" value="3" id="no3" name="no3" onclick="calc(this)"></input type="button" value=""><br />
        <input type="button" value="-" id="no1" name="t" onclick="calc(this)">
        <input type="button" value="*" id="no1" name="z" onclick="calc(this)">
        <input type="button" value="=" id="no1" name="e" onclick="calc(this)">
            <!--This line works correctly-->
        <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="DoIt"  VALUE="  =  " OnClick="document.calc1.res.value = eval(document.calc1.res.value)">
        <input type="button" value="/" id="no1" name="d" onclick="calc(this)">
        <input type="button" value="+" id="no1" name="j" onclick="calc(this)">


    </form>
```

In HTML code there is two equal signs. My problem is there.

When I wanted to evaluate expression in the JS file it did not work, but it was working in HTML file. I mentioned lines with comments.

What are differences between these  lines?

Comment: TIP: Avoid the use of `eval()` at all costs. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea

Comment: What's going on here? Why are you using `eval` at all?

Comment: `document.getElementById('res').value`

Comment: @RGraham as I said, I am new in js. I google simple calculator and all of them used **eval()**! Why I should not use this function?

Comment: im not sure, but isnt 'calc1' supposed to be the id for it to be accessed like you do?

Comment: you shouldnt use eval because if you do `eval(a)` and get the `a` from user input, and he accidentally inputs `a = malicious script to destroy the matrix` , it will result in `eval(malicious script to destroy the matrix)`

Comment: @Banana So, How should I eval/execute like **eval()** without this function?

Comment: Don't avoid `eval` at all costs. That's nonsense. Be careful with it, understand it, then use it to great effect.

Comment: you simply do `if(op=='+'){ return +a + +b;}`

Comment: @Banana If the user wants to input arbitrary code, they open Dev Tools??

Comment: @CarlSmith thats why i said 'accidentally'. eval()'s behaviour can be unpredictable, and of course he can use it and probably as a beginner he should test it out, but i would avoid it beyond testing.

Answer (score 0):

1.) DON'T USE `eval()`! You don't need to.

2.) To get all of the forms in a document, do `[document].forms`. Then put `.calc1` to get a specific form by name then put `.res` to get a specific field by name.

```
function calc(num1Elem, opElem, num2Elem){
    var num1 = parseInt(num1Elem.value, 10);
    if (num2Elem) var num2 = parseInt(num2Elem.value, 10);
    var op = opElem.value;
    var num;
    if(op == "-") num = num1-num2;
    else if(op == "*") num = num1*num2;
    else if(op == "=") num = num1;
    else if(op == "+") num = num1+num2;
    else if(op == "/") num = num1/num2;
    else op ="";
    if (op != "") {
        document.forms.calc1.res.value = num;
        //Do NOT use eval():
        // document.forms.calc1.res.value = eval(num1+op+num2);
        // This won't even work if we use the = sign.
    }
    //The else loop just sets something equal to what it already is, so it's not doing anything, so we can omit it.
}

//Type in one of these lines of code and sees what happens now!
calc(document.forms.calc1.no8, document.forms.calc1.e, document.forms.calc1.no7)
calc(document.forms.calc1.no8, document.forms.calc1.j, document.forms.calc1.no7)
calc(document.forms.calc1.no8, document.forms.calc1.t, document.forms.calc1.no7)
calc(document.forms.calc1.no8, document.forms.calc1.z, document.forms.calc1.no7)
calc(document.forms.calc1.no8, document.forms.calc1.d, document.forms.calc1.no7)
```